# Jquery eq(index out of bound) and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is actually two question. I was playing around with the .eq method in [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and decided to test it out using jsfiddle. What puzzles me is that when I supply an index that is obviously out of bound it still returns me an obj instead of an index out of bound error.

```
console.log($("body").children("div").eq(2));
console.log($("body").children("div").eq(20));
```

So I did this using the .children method from [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/children/). Upon closer inspection if I specify a selector it gives me the correct children, but if I do not it also returns the title element which is outside of the body.

```
console.log($("body").children());
console.log($("body").children("div"));
```

Does anybody know why? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVtF3/3/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No Index out of bounds

This was just a choice of the jQuery developers.  If a selector returns no results, it will be an empty jQuery collection rather than return an error.

```
$("body").children("div").eq(20).length === 0
```

#### `<title>` appears in `<body>`

jsfiddle.net automatically has `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` elements.  Everything in the HTML frame is already wrapped in `<body>`.  The `<body>` you provide is ignored. I do find it odd that `<title>` ends up being acceptable there, though.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the case of your jsfiddle, jsfiddle automatically injects everything you type in the html area into a body tag, this your example ends up rendering something like the following, so as you can see, title IS a child of body.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <title></title>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```